# Machine-learning friendly data organization

Tags: json, database, machine-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction

There are a lot of tutorials online about different machine learning tools (neural networks and various related techniques like DL, ID trees, SVMs). When I do small-scale machine learning, in python or MATLAB or equivalent, I usually have a CSV file with features and a CSV file with labels, I load these files into memory and then organize them as demanded by the program (ex. Matrix for matlab).

I am collecting data for performance of a system in real time. Every single few minutes, I collect a lot of data, and currently I store it in a Json format {Key: value}, etc. I usually collect this data and store it just for an hour to see how my system is doing. What I want to do instead is keep it and try to do some machine learning on it. I am wondering what the rules of thumb are for organizing datasets for machine learning, especially because I am not sure what kind of ML I want to do (this is an exploration project, so I am trying to figure out a way to enable myself to do the most exploration).

I read this blog article:https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/datascience/preparing-your-dataset-for-machine-learning-8-basic-techniques-that-make-your-data-better/

> The companies that started data collection with paper ledgers and
>   ended with .xlsx and .csv files will likely have a harder time with
>   data preparation than those who have a small but proud ML-friendly
>   dataset.

It said that .csv data sets are not friendly for ML. Are there some ways to save the data that are considered to be more optimal for ML?

Here are a few use cases that I am thinking about:

1. Classification using point in time data paired with a label
2. Classification using time series (organized in a single matrix)
   paired with a label
3. Regression: predict value of X given a matrix of
   its time series values

I do not have a particular problem in mind. Rather, I want to start to set up this data set in a way that enables Machine Learning in the future.

My question is: what are the more popular ways to store data as to enable Machine Learning?

Some options:

CSV organized by time:

```
Time_stamp, feature1, feature2, feature3,...,featureN
Time_stamp, feature1, feature2, feature3,...,featureN
Time_stamp, feature1, feature2, feature3,...,featureN
...
```

And some starter labels (that may or may not be augmented later)

```
Time_stamp, label1, label2....labelN
Time_stamp, label1, label2....labelN
Time_stamp, label1, label2....labelN
```

Json-style key-value pairs:

```
{
time_stamp: _,
feature1: _,
feature2: _,
...,
featureN:_,
label1:_,
label2:_,
label3:_,
...
}
```

Say I decide that I want to use time series to predict labels... Then I would have to get time-series data all into one feature set for labels.

I understand that there are many ways to tackle this (one being: forget about organization - just write an API and when you figure out a problem to solve, produce this nicely organized data set for your problem), but really, I wonder what the rules of thumb are for designing the data--side infrastructure for machine learning in industry and academia.

Some issues that arise:

- What if you want to add a new feature?
- What if you have a new label?
- What if you do not want to consider just single point time features, but use time-series of features in analysis?

I do not know much about databases, so wisdom is appreciated, and so are feature storage related online resources. Most of the ones I find have to do with the models, or the ML infrastructure - not the enablement or the data organization piece I am interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most of the machine learning libraries I have worked with (tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, R), data is usually worked with in a tabular format (like CSV) because under the hood many machine learning algorithms are implement using fast linear algebra code. So I am not sure what the article is on about but storing data in the CSV format is fine.

Data cleaning, organisation and storage are big topics. Your data cleaning pipeline (and your whole training process) should be reproducible, [this paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003285) has some nice principles to keep in mind. [This article by Hadley Wickham](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/) has some nice thoughts about how to organise data in a tabular format. If your dataset is complicated or you are going to be frequently reusing it, it's probably worth storing in a database and I recommend picking up a guide to SQL and also data warehousing.